# How to process audio stream

Tags: javascript, stream, webassembly, opus

I am completely inexperienced in dealing with data streams and wanted to feed a getUserMedia into an opus converter as a learning project and then - maybe too naive - send it via socket.io.
My - maybe wrong idea - is that I am constantly dividing and converting the stream in pieces.

I am grateful for all explanations that explain the general stream handling a bit better, as I said it is a learning project, I know that with WebRTC a much better solution is available.

As encoder I wanted to use https://github.com/ImagicTheCat/libopusjs. Alternatives are welcome but I would like to stick with the idea of a wasm based encoder.

What I have so far (As the first step, my idea was to encode the stream and decode and output it again):

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
      console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({audio: true, video: true})
      .then(function(stream) {
          video.srcObject = stream;
          video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
              video.play();
              video.muted = true;
          };

          var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
          var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);


          var enc = new libopus.Encoder(1,48000,24000,20,false);
=> enc stream
          var dec = new libopus.Decoder(1,48000);

=> perspectively send this enc stream via socketio
=> dec enc stream => RESULT stream




          RESULT.connect(audioCtx.destination);

      })
      .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('The following gUM error occured: ' + err);
      });
  } else {
     console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
  }
```

Comment: have a look at this too: [61292834](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61292834/encode-audiobuffer-with-opus-or-other-codec-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen these WASM modules?

- [opus-recorder](https://github.com/chris-rudmin/opus-recorder) encodes/decodes Ogg Opus and provides lots of options.
- [opus-stream-decoder](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder) is more limited but decodes Ogg Opus asynchronously in chunks.