# Encode AudioBuffer with Opus (or other codec) in Browser

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, opus

I am trying to stream Audio via Websocket.

I can get an AudioBuffer from the Microphone (or other Source) via Web-Audio-Api and stream the RAW-Audio-Buffer, but i think this would not be very efficient.
So i looked arround to encode the AudioBuffer somehow. - If the Opus-Codec would not be practicable, 
i am open to alternatives and thankful for any hints in the right direction.

I have tried to use the MediaRecorder (from MediaStreamRecording-API) but it seems not possible to stream with that API, instead of plain recording.

Here is the Part how i get the RAW-AudioBuffer:

```js
const handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    const context = new AudioContext();
    const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    const processor = context.createScriptProcessor(16384, 1, 1);

    source.connect(processor);
    processor.connect(context.destination);

    processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
    
      bufferLen = e.inputBuffer.length
        const inputBuffer = new Float32Array(bufferLen);
        e.inputBuffer.copyFromChannel(inputBuffer, 0);

        let data_to_send = inputBuffer


    
      //And send the Float32Array ...
    
    }

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
      .then(handleSuccess);
```

So the Main Question is: How can i encode the AudioBuffer.
(and Decode it at the Receiver)
Is there an API or Library? Can i get the encoded Buffer from another API in the Browser?

Comment: It is definitely possible to stream the output of MediaRecorder, at a 1-second or so delay.  If this isn't sufficient for your needs, you should be using WebRTC anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The Web Audio API has a [MediaStreamDestination node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination) that will expose a `.stream` MediaStream that you can then pass through the [WebRTC API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API).

But if you are only dealing with a microphone input, then pass directly that MediaStream to WebRTC, no need for the Web Audio step.

---

Ps: for the ones that only want to encode to opus, then MediaRecorder is currently the only native way. It will incur a delay, will generate a webm file, not only the raw data, and will process the data no faster than real-time.

Only other options now are to write your own encoders and run it in WabAssembly.

Hopefully in a near future, we'll have access to the [WebCodecs API](https://github.com/WICG/web-codecs/blob/master/explainer.md) which should solve this use case among others.